# Tensorflow clone_model with subclass model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to clone a subclass-based model in Tensorflow? For example, if I have the following model:

```py
class MySequentialModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.dense_1 = FlexibleDense(out_features=3)
    self.dense_2 = FlexibleDense(out_features=2)
  def call(self, x):
    x = self.dense_1(x)
    return self.dense_2(x)
```

Then I train save, and load the model, when I try to clone it:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(original_model)
```

I get `` ValueError: Expected `model` argument to be a functional `Model` instance, but got a subclass model instead. ``
Is there some other way to clone a model which is a subclass of `tf.keras.Model`?

Comment: Found the similar issue resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266916/how-to-copy-a-tf-keras-models-model-subclass). Which says, we can't use `tf.keras.models.clone_model` for `subclassed model API` whereas we can use it for `sequential` and `functional API`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but the issue is tracked on the Keras repository [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17261).