# How to copy a tf.keras.models.Model subclass?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to copy a keras model and there is no way that I know of which can be done unless the model **is not** a `tf.keras.models.Model()` subclass.

**Note:** The use `copy.deepcopy()` will work without giving any errors however it will result in another error whenever the copy is used.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    if training:
      x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
    return self.dense2(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model1 = MyModel()
    model2 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model1)
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emadboctor/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 600, in <module>
    model2 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 430, in clone_model
    return _clone_functional_model(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 171, in _clone_functional_model
    raise ValueError('Expected `model` argument '
ValueError: Expected `model` argument to be a functional `Model` instance, but got a subclass model instead.
```

Comment: Instantiate model2 as MyModel(), then copy the weights and biases to model2 from model1. That might work.

Comment: I want to avoid calling `MyModel()` several times, that's the whole point, because `MyModel` can have many arguments and the less repetition, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we can't use `tf.keras.models.clone_model` for subclassed model API whereas we can for sequential and functional API. From [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/clone_model),

```
model   Instance of Model (could be a functional model or a Sequential model).
```

Here is a workaround for your need. It makes sense if we need to copy a trained model, where we can get some optimized parameters. So, the main task is we need to create a new model by copying an existing model. The most convenient way for now of this scenario is to `get` trained weight and `set` to the newly created model instances. Let first build a model, train it and then get and set weight matrices to the new model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class ModelSubClassing(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(ModelSubClassing, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, activation="relu")
        self.gap   = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        # forward pass: block 1 
        x = self.conv1(input_tensor)
        x = self.gap(x)
        return self.dense(x)

    def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=raw_shape)
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))


# compile 
sub_classing_model = ModelSubClassing(10)
sub_classing_model.compile(
        loss      = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics   = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

# plot for debug 
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    sub_classing_model.build_graph(x_train.shape[1:]),
    show_shapes=False,
    show_dtype=False,
    show_layer_names=True,
    expand_nested=False,
    dpi=96,
)
```

[image]

**DataSet**

```
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# train set / data 
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
# train set / target 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)

# fit 
sub_classing_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=1)
# 469/469 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 8.2821
```

**New Model / Copy**

For the subclasses model, we have to initiate the class object.

```
sub_classing_model_copy = ModelSubClassing(10)
sub_classing_model_copy.build((x_train.shape))
sub_classing_model_copy.set_weights(sub_classing_model.get_weights()) # <- get and set wg

# plot for debug ; same as original plot
# but know, layer name is no longer same
# i.e. if, old: conv2d_40 , new/copy: conv2d_41
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    sub_classing_model_copy.build_graph(x_train.shape[1:]),
    show_shapes=False,
    show_dtype=False,
    show_layer_names=True,
    expand_nested=False,
    dpi=96,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def clones(module, N):
  
    Creation of N identical layers.
    :param module: module to clone
    :param N: number of copies
    :return: keras model of module copies
  
    seqm=KM.Sequential()
    for i in range(N):
        m = copy.deepcopy(module)
        m.name=m.name+str(i)
        seqm.add(m)
    return seqm
```